# how to use resize in js several times

Tags: javascript

i'm making a webpage and i want when this page resized do a function
but it works just for first time not for every time that page resized
and my codes is below:
any suggestion ?

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">    
<script>
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

function myFunction() {
   if(width<500){
                   document.getElementById("yy").style.display="none";
   }else{
        document.getElementById("yy").style.display="absolute";
   }

}
</script>
<img id="yy src="..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to change styles for element if page width less than 500px, you can use css [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Media queries don't work on IE8 and below, so be sure you don't need to support old browsers, in that case you need to use javascript.

```
/* css rules for your example */

#yy {
     display: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* this rules will apply only when screen width less than 500px */


    #yy {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It's much easier to write and much easier to maintain.